# Strategy for bail out when dealing with pipes, fork

Tags: c, error-handling, fork

I wrote a little program using `fork` to create new processes which use `pipe`s to communicate. Applying defensive programming, I check every return value. If a return value indicates that something went wrong, I want to free all resources, close all pipes and the parent process to wait on it's child processes to terminate.  Now, what's the best way to bail out if an error occurs?

At the moment, I'm doing it this way:

```
    /* initialize pipes */
if(pipe(p1fd) == -1) {
    (void) printError("Could not init pipe 1");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
if(pipe(p2fd) == -1) {
    (void) printError("Could not init pipe 2");
    (void) close(p1fd[0]);
    (void) close(p1fd[1]); 
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

switch (pid = fork()) {
    case -1: 
        (void) printError("Could not fork");
        (void) close(p1fd[0]);
        (void) close(p1fd[1]);
        (void) close(p2fd[0]);
        (void) close(p2fd[1]);  
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        break;
    case 0: /* child process */
        break;
    default: /* parent process */       
        break;
}
```

This gets quite cumbersome if one needs more resources. Another way I thought of was providing a bailout function that simply closes all pipes without caring if the pipes have actually been opened (same for freeing memory and calling `wait` on child processes). But then, all variables needed in such a bail out function would have to be global, since some of the pipes are passed on to different child processes/functions.

Comment: @mort: You don't check any return value of `close ()` system call. Neither you expect `exit ()` not to exit :-)

Comment: @Vlad: Well, `exit()`does not have a return value.

Comment: @mort: But in theory, it could not do the job, right? So that next line of code, if any, could get executed. I'd add `_exit ()` after that, and then call `die ()` in a loop to make it defensive :))

Comment: @Vlad: I trust ANSI-C to do what the man pages say. What would you do if `exit()`does not work?

Comment: Well, the thing is - it doesn't make any sense to `close ()` file descriptors before calling `exit ()`, because they will get closed anyway when kernel terminates the process. So why bother at all?

Comment: Good question. However, usually assignments at university explicitly state that all resources must be closed and all memory be freed before calling èxit()`. Any idea why?

Comment: @VladLazarenko: `exit` does not have a return value, it also doesn't return. the `gcc` optimizer will eliminate any code following exit for this reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `goto` to avoid repeating the same code in each of the failure branches:

```
if (pipe(p1fd) == -1) {
    printError("Could not init pipe 1");
    goto pipe1_fail;
}

if (pipe(p2fd) == -1) {
    printError("Could not init pipe 2");
    goto pipe2_fail;
}

switch (pid = fork()) {
    case -1: 
        printError("Could not fork");
        goto fork_fail;

    case 0: /* child process */
        ...
        exit(...);

    default: /* parent process */       
        ...
        exit(...);
}

fork_fail:
close(p2fd[0]);
close(p2fd[1]);

pipe2_fail:
close(p1fd[0]);
close(p1fd[1]);

pipe1_fail:
exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
```

Answer (score 2):

Although `goto` is frowned upon by some people, it is often [used for error handling](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/goto.html), e. g. [in the Linux kernel](http://kerneltrap.org/node/553/2131). But be careful to keep your code well-structured then, and don't exaggerate in using this.

Example here:

```
/* initialize pipes */
if(pipe(p1fd) == -1) {
    (void) printError("Could not init pipe 1");
    goto error;
}

if(pipe(p2fd) == -1) {
    (void) printError("Could not init pipe 2");
    goto closep1fd;
}

switch (pid = fork()) {
    case -1: 
        (void) printError("Could not fork");
        goto closep2p1fd;
    case 0: /* child process */
        break;
    default: /* parent process */       
        break;
}   

closep2p1fd:
    close(p2fd[0]);
    close(p2fd[1]); 
closep1fd:
    close(p1fd[0]);
    close(p1fd[1]); 
error:
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    return -1; // maybe better if it is a deeply nested function
```